# Unexpected Results in Laravel Eager Loading With Constraints

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

I have two tables: `assets` and `asset_classifications`. The tables have one-to-many relationship, where an `asset` has one asset classification, and `asset_classifications` have many assets.

I'm trying to run a query to get all assets which has an `asset_classification` name of "laptops", for example. I'm trying to do this by running this eager load with a constraint:

```
$laptops = Asset::with(array('classification'=>function($query){
    $query->where("name","=","laptops");
}))->get();

foreach($laptops as $laptop){
    echo $laptop->serial_number."<br/>";
}
```

`name` is a column from `asset_classifications` table. I already formed the one-to-many relationship by setting up the needed methods for my `Asset` and `AssetClassification` models.

The problem with my eager load is that it gets all the assets, seeming to ignore my eager loading constraint which tries to get only the "laptops". I think the problem is in my code or my understanding of eager loading, but I don't know which. I'm still new to this and I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with` is used to filter related models, while you need `whereHas` for filtering main queried model by related table constraints:

```
$laptops = Asset::whereHas('classification', function ($query) {
    $query->where("name","=","laptops");
})->get();
```

Comment: Although I don't quite get the difference between whereHas and the eager loading constraint.

Comment: The difference is this: `with` loads all assets but only filtered related classifications, while `whereHas` filters assets by related classifications (and doesn't load the latter at all, unless you use `with` again..)